# Is it possible to increase the size of cell in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I want to insert a 16MB image with blob type in Cassandra.

However, I noticed that the practical limit on blob size is less than 1 MB.
(The description of blob type is [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_reference/blob_r.html).)

Except splitting the image into multiple 1MB, I'm wondering if it is possible to increase the size of the cell to handle my requirement.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The 1Mb limit specified in the documentation is a recommendation, not a hard limit.  And it's a good recommendation, because otherwise you can get problems with maintenance operations, like, repair, bootstrapping of the new nodes, etc. - I've seen cases (on older Cassandra) when people stored 1Mb blobs, and couldn't add the new data center because bootstrap failed. Nowadays, it shouldn't be a problem, but this recommendation still actual.

Usual recommendation is to store file content on the file system and store metadata, including the file path in Cassandra. By doing that, it's easier to host your images, especially if you're in the cloud - this will be more performant, and cheaper...

Comment: Completely agree. I should add that I've seen a Cassandra used for JSON data that sometime could contain images larger than 16MB. It worked, but the P99 coordinator latency was awful, just because of the effort to transfer 100MB+ of data from one node to another when the nodes are not on the same rack or datacenter.